# I just made a song, its called "Ain't going there no way no how". Bards are useless cowards, how do I make them useful in combat?

Tags: warfare, medieval

This guy said he was an adventurer, we paid him to help us on a mission to kill some orcs. Because screw orcs!

Turns out the guy really is just an useless bard, his sword is just for show, all he can do is sing and play a stupid small harp. Totally not worth the money, but the contract was clear....we had to pay in advance and the guy had great charisma so we couldn't refuse.

Now we are stuck with the useless idiot and we can't kill him, might as well use him to get the job done.

How can I use a bard to kill  30 orc warriors (not all at once), considering our team composed of 4 excellent fighters and a useless bard. Our plan was to just get chased by a bunch of orcs on horseback and lure them into traps but the bard is not even a skilled rider, he would just fall into the traps instead of skipping them.

Wasting money is something I hate, and I invested into that guy I will make an use out of him!

I need a way to give this useless bard an use in combat, what can I do?

Comment: How does this pertain to world building?

Comment: I mean, you can use him as bait for an ambush, but if we're talking about an actual bard rather than the D&D variety, you won't get much else in terms of combat.

Comment: @Mr.Anderson how does it not?

Comment: This seems like a textbook example of a "storytelling" rather than "worldbuilding" question. That is, it's not about how your world works, but how a specific person or people in that world "should" act - which is explicitly off-topic here per the [help/on-topic].

Comment: You have four excellent fighters. Politely ask for your money back. Then ask slightly less politely. Increment impoliteness until money is returned.

Comment: @user535733 next time I hope they don't lie on the résumé

Comment: Wait...you paid your fighters *in advance?* Your accountant will be furious. Your *mother* will be furious. "I didn't raise my child to be such a fool..."

Comment: @Sixteen: This question has been closed. You might have more success if the question was "In this world why do raiding parties hire bards so often?" rather than "What can this one raiding party do with their bard?". You can either change the question or start an entirely new one. Really my answer applies to the first question rather than what you asked.

Comment: @Sixteen: I've put more stuff in just in case your bard is a traveling performer rather than the multitalented D&D sort of bard.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Jack of all Trades.**

Your bard is not much use in a fight. But this trip is going to take a few weeks and the bard is a great addition to the party for everything except combat. He can cook and play music at camp to keep morale high; wrap wounds and set broken bones; polish and sharpen weapons; speak several languages (in particular Orc). He knows the wilderness enough to gather game so we don't have to eat dry rations; he can track a group of orcs; and make it harder for them to track us.

Since the bard has loads of non-combat skills it means we can hire Rockchin McAxeface and his three brothers to make up the rest of our party. Those guys only do one thing but they do it well.

In combat your bard stays in the back and tries to twang things with his hunting bow. Not much use but it keeps him out of trouble. He also acts as runner when we split the party.

**Edit: Executive Advertising Officer**

ALRIGHT HERE SONNY NOW LISTEN UP. We've already paid you the money so we're gonna get something out of you like it or not. Your job is to follow us around and not get killed. After the battle your job is to write an heroic lay about our victory over the orcs. Then tour the local taverns and work the song into your repetoire. Also you have to wear this cloak with our company's symbol of a flaming skull and recommend everyone hire the Flaming Skulls when they need something killed.

Comment: Slight improvement: He knows the Orc language and can "throw" his voice. That should work well enough for leading Orcs into the traps. In addition, he is well trained in Orcish music and songs. They hear the song, come to the clearing, get trapped and killed. He can also listen to Orc sentries and recognize when they change watch (once every 4 hours), so you can kill the guards just after the watch change and easily slaughter sleeping Orcs.

Comment: @jo1storm I was mainly thinking of "sneak and listen" ideas like your sentries idea. But of course there are a million uses to knowing what your enemies are talking about. I believe Throw Voice is a level 2 Bard ability that can be used 3 times a day. Hiring a level 2 bard is a little more expensive.